# Webscraping: Can´t access logged using authenticate{httr}

Tags: r

I´m trying to do webscraping in order to get information from the 'Odds Archive' in the webpage 'http://www.oddsoddsodds.com/'. The question is that I need to be logged to access to this information but I can´t get it using authenticate from the package httr. Am I doing anything wrong or are there any other way to get it?

```
web <-'http://www.oddsoddsodds.com/goto/odds/s1/g2268749/m1/d0/'
GET(web,authenticate("user", "passwd"))
```

Comment: Have you tried these credentials directly from the actual site to verify that they be correct?

Comment: You have to research how to actually log in to that website with R. `authenticate()` will attempt HTTP authentication, and I'm guessing the website doesn't support that.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to fill the login-form and to click on the submit button with the following code :

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
url <- "https://www.oddsportal.com/"
shell('docker run -d -p 4446:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4446L, browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate(url)

web_Obj_Login <- remDr$findElement('xpath', '//*[@id="app"]/div/header/div[2]/div[5]/div[1]')
web_Obj_Login$clickElement()

web_Obj_Username <- remDr$findElement('xpath', '//*[@id="login-username-sign"]')
web_Obj_Username$sendKeysToElement(list("allo@gmail.com"))

web_Obj_Password <- remDr$findElement('xpath', '//*[@id="login-password-sign-m"]')
web_Obj_Password$sendKeysToElement(list("xxx"))

web_Obj_Submit <- remDr$findElement('xpath', '/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[4]/span/input')
web_Obj_Submit$clickElement()
```

I used RSelenium instead of httr. I think it could still be of interest.